# Newton's Identity

Tags: quadratics, newton-series

While reading about quadratic equations, I came across Newton's Identity formula which said we can express $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ in simpler forms but not given any explanation. They wrote $S_n=\alpha^n+\beta^n$ and plugged in the quadratic equation $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ to write: $$f(x)=aS_{n+1}+bS_n+cS_{n-1}$$ Also what if we want to find for any polynomial the value: $$\alpha^n-\beta^n$$ I went through articles on internet but they have some very complicated proofs. I want to understand how do we derive this in a simple manner and what have they exactly done with the quadratic equation? Some examples would make it very clear to understand. Thanks

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried and where are you stuck

Comment: @JitendraSingh, I have read it for the first time and I haven't understood what the TB is trying to convey and want to know exactly how do we use this? Some examples would make it clear

Comment: What is $f(x)$ first? Do we need Newton polynomials for the question, or this is just some misleading discussion? If we really need Newton polynomials, where is one such polynomial used in the question, best with clear notation?! And which is exactly the question? You want examples for what exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\a}{\alpha}\newcommand{\b}{\beta}$Consider the quadratic equation $$x^2 - (\a + \b)x + \a\b = 0.$$
It is easy to see that $\a$ and $\b$ both satisfy the equation. In particular, this means that $$x^2 = (\a + \b)x - \a\b$$
for $x = \a, \b$. Multiplying by $x^n$ for $n \geqslant 0$, we get $$x^{n + 2} = (\a + \b) x^{n + 1} - \a\b x^n.$$

The above is also satisfied by $\a$ and $\b$ both. Thus, adding the corresponding equations for $\a$ and $\b$, we get $$S_{n + 2} = (\a + \b) S_{n + 1} - \a\b S_n$$ for all $n \geqslant 0$. (With the convention that $S_0 := 2$.)

---

This technique similarly gives you the recursion for $\a^n - \b^n$ as well. I leave that to you.

Comment: The notations in the OP, $a,b,c$ for the coefficients of some $f(x)$, which should be $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ but is displayed in a way that should forbid an answer first, and then $\alpha,\beta$ for the roots, yes, the notations are not so good. But to go from $a,b,c;\alpha,\beta$ to $a,b,c;a,b$ is worse...

Comment: @dan_fulea: I've changed $a, b$ to $\alpha, \beta$.

Comment: Yes, this is much better, thanks for the edit!

Comment: What are the "corresponding equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$"?

Comment: @PeterPhipps: The equations you get by plugging $x$ as $\alpha$ and $\beta$. More explicitly: $\newcommand{\a}{\alpha}\newcommand{\b}{\beta}$
$$\a^{n + 2} = (\a + \b) \a^{n + 1} - \a\b \a^n, \\
\b^{n + 2} = (\a + \b) \b^{n + 1} - \a\b \b^n.$$

Comment: @AryamanMaithani is there a difference b/w $\geqslant$ and $\geq$ or are they same? Thanks

Comment: @Algebrology: They're the same mathematically, these days I prefer $\geqslant$ for (purely) aesthetic reasons. :-)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Thanks for your reply :)